# How to print debug message in the OpenBMC

Tags: c++, printf, cout, openbmc

I want to print debug message in the bmcweb of OpenBMC. The development language of OpenBMC is c++, and I print the message through printf and cout, but it does't work. In the console of qemu, I can not see any message I print ....

Any one could help me ? >__<
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

In the OpenBMC console, enter journalctl to show system log.

Answer (score 0):

It works to use printf and look at the journalctl (`journalctl -u bmcweb`), for quick debugging. However, bmcweb does a have logging wrapper that would be better for long term code changes.

> [BMCWEB_LOG_ERROR](https://github.com/openbmc/bmcweb/blob/fcc5aa66f2dca9f33c70df8dcd828ac4f31d7a92/http/logging.hpp#L13) << "UNIX socket: async_accept error = ";

Then make sure BMCWEB_ENABLE_LOGGING is set in the recipe build.

Comment: That's right, I enabled BMCWEB_ENABLE_LOGGING, the log is displayed correctly, thank you for your help!